# TargetInvocationException thrown when executing ExecuteNonQuery in Parallel using SMO

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, smo

**Overview**

I have been working for quite some time trying to find a post that addresses my particular situation, but have come up empty. I am attempting to create a C# .NET console application that will parse an XML file with multiple database restore definitions, and then subsequently launch those restores in parallel using SQL Management Objects. After each restore, the user may specify zero to many SQL files that they would wish to run against the newly restored database. Whenever I attempt more than 4 of these jobs in parallel, the static method handling the execution of SQL files against the database chokes on calling the ExecuteNonQuery() method against the locally created ServerConnection. Am I implementing this incorrectly? Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

**Attempted solutions**

- Using Parallel.ForEach loop to execute jobs
- Using Task.Factory.StartNew() to execute jobs

In both of the above methods, I am calling out to two static methods:

1. One that handles the restore using SMO.
2. One that handles the execution of of SQL scripts against the database using SMO.

**Calling code**

```
            Parallel.ForEach(restores.Restore,
            //new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4},
            restore => 
            {
                //Grab copies of the backup information
                string backup = restore.Backup;
                string server = restore.Server;
                string database = restore.Database;
                string[] patchFiles = restore.PatchFiles;

                //Begin by restoring the database from the backup file
                RestoreDatabaseFromBackup(backup, server, database);

                //Execute each patch file sequentially for the restore defintion
                foreach (string patchFile in patchFiles)
                {
                    ExecutePatchFile(patchFile, server, database);
                }
            });
```

**ExecutePathFile Method**

```
private static void ExecutePatchFile(string patchFile, string server, string database)
    {
        //Create directory for the log file (if it doesn't already exist)
        DirectoryInfo di = CreateLogFileDirectory(server, database);

        //Create the log file
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(di.FullName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(patchFile) + ".log"));

        Console.WriteLine("{0} : Beginning execution of {1} for {2} on {3}.", DateTime.Now, patchFile, database, server);

        //Verify that 'patchFile' exists and is of the right file extension
        if (!File.Exists(patchFile) || Path.GetExtension(patchFile) != ".sql")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : Could not execute {1} for {2} on {3}. Invalid SQL file.", DateTime.Now, Path.GetFileName(patchFile), database, server);
            sw.WriteLine("{0} : Could not execute {1} for {2} on {3}. Invalid SQL file.", DateTime.Now, Path.GetFileName(patchFile), database, server);
            sw.Close();
            return;
        }

        string script = File.ReadAllText(patchFile);

        try
        {
            //Build out connection string
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sb.DataSource = server;
            sb.InitialCatalog = database;
            sb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            //Create SqlConnection
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());
            //Set sqlCon to treat exceptions as infomessages
            sqlCon.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

            //Create ServerConnection
            ServerConnection serverCon = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);

            serverCon.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler((sender, e) => ConnectionContext_InfoMessage(sender, e, sw));
            serverCon.ExecuteNonQuery(script, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Close();
        }

    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=BatchDatabaseRestorer
  StackTrace:
       at BatchDatabaseRestorer.Program.ExecutePatchFile(String patchFile, String server, String database) in c:\Users\zannett\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BatchDatabaseRestorer\BatchDatabaseRestorer\Program.cs:line 224
       at BatchDatabaseRestorer.Program.<Main>b__0(RestoresRestore restore) in c:\Users\zannett\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BatchDatabaseRestorer\BatchDatabaseRestorer\Program.cs:line 83
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass21`2.<ForEachWorker>b__17(Int32 i)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
  InnerException: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=Parse error occurred while looking for GO statement. Line 0.
       Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecuteBatch.GetStatements(String sqlCommand)
       InnerException: ManagedBatchParser.ParserException
            HResult=-2146233088
            Message=""
            Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser
            StackTrace:
                 at ManagedBatchParser.Parser.Parse()
                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecuteBatch.GetStatements(String sqlCommand)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: What is the content of `script`?

Comment: In the cases that I've tested, it is a TSQL script that updates many stored procedures on the database with multiple GO keywords throughout. By default, I believe the ServerContext object treats the GO keyword as the batch separator. This causes the ExecuteNonQuery() method to execute the script as a batch execution.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the exception message? I've found numerous answers to that problem (I'm talking about `Parse error occurred while looking for GO statement. Line 0.`)

Comment: I have... The strange thing is that with my parallelization less than 4 instances, I don't have a problem at all. The file parses just fine. It is only when the parallelization count rises above 4 that this exception is thrown.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the parallel reading of the file. Is there anyone writing to that file?

Comment: There is not. Just multiple readers accessing the same file.

Comment: Try reading the file once, and re-using it inside that method.

Comment: Even after reading the file once before the Parallel.ForEach loop, the exception will be thrown. I've started placing locks around different sections to determine where the problem is. I've narrowed it down to the .ExecuteNonQuery() call on the ServerConnection object. The next thing I'm going to try is to parse the script on the GO statements and pass the pre-parsed StringCollection to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem calling ExecuteNonQuery() on multiple ServerConnection instances in parallel when you let it handle the parsing internally. If I split the script along the GO keywords myself, and then pass in the commands as a StringCollection (per one of the available overrides), then the command executes fine regardless of the number of parallel jobs. This leads me to believe that the Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient object or the Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser object is not compatible with parallel execution per the implementation of ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question because I have the very same Exception thrown at me. I'm parsing `DateTime` from strings via reflection and I'm pretty sure the `TargetInvocationException` is replacing the `FormatException` because I'm using `MethodInfo.Invoke` to call the parse method of DateTime. After replacing that with the usual `DateTime.Parse` I get the FormatException. So my strings are malformed or the parser is not in the correct state (Culture etc.).

So I guess the CLR is replacing any exception thrown by an **invoked** function with `TargetInvocationException`. You could check your strings and look for complex objects to parse, since it seems to be the parser causing your problems.